# MexFunction crashing while assigning matrix entry

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

In a mex function I have the following code

```
double c[a][b][b*2-1];

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    for (int l = 0; l < b; l++) {
        for (int m = -l; m <= l; m++) {

           c[i][l][m+l] = some_function();

         }
    }
}
```

And it crashes. I've checked the values of a, b. Both are positive integer.

Even if I try to execute this simple command instead of the loops

```
c[0][0][0] = 1.0;
```

MATLAB crashes.

What can I do?

(Except using mxArray...)

Comment: `double c[a][b][b*2-1];` is not standard C++ unless `a` and `b` are compile time constants.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's more than likely crashing for a different reason if `c[0][0][0] = 1.0;` is causing it to crash, and you've checked `a` and `b` are both positive integers.

Comment: @NathanOliver In that case the code just won't compile. OP seems to be getting run time errors.

Comment: @NathanOliver how can one create dynamic array otherwise?

Comment: @user1384636 use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or dynamically allocate the array with `new`.

Comment: @user1384636 - MATLAB uses C89, so that array declaration will cause unexpected behaviour.  You need to use `malloc / mxMalloc` on that array before using it.

Comment: @user1384636, are you returning `c` to MATLAB via an `mxArray`? If so, that will cause the crash since `c` will be cleaned up when this function returns since it is stack allocated. If the memory is being returned to MATLAB, `mxMalloc/mxCalloc` **must** be used to allocate the memory so that: 1. The lifetime persists beyond your MEX function 2. The memory is properly aligned.